# Will Derby, H2, or SQLite give faster load time and/or smaller file size than HSQL?

Tags: database-design, sqlite, derby, h2, hsqldb

I have some flat files with the following columns; 3 integers, 3 reals, and 1 varchar(20). For querying I need an index that contains both 1 of the integer columns and the varchar column.  Each file is around 1.8GB in size with around 38 million rows.

Currently I am using a HSQL(Standalone) database to load a file for processing; one database per file. It is very slow to load (120+ min) the file and results in a 4.7GB database file when the database is created with the following options.

```
"Properties" -> {
  "check_props" -> "true",
  "shutdown" -> "true",
  "hsqldb.default_table_type" -> "cached",
  "sql.syntax_mss" -> "true",
  "hsqldb.log_data" -> "false",
  "hsqldb.inc_backup" -> "false" 
  }
```

The file read in batches of 100k records.  The read is very fast (almost instant) so I do not think it is the read that is slowing things down.  It also takes a very long time to close the connection to the database.

I have the option to use Derby, H2, or SQLite.  Will any of these result in faster load time and/or smaller database file size in this scenario?  If so what are the connection string options that should be used to achieve this?  Alternatively, are there different connection string options I can use with HSQL(Standalone) that will reduce the load time and/or database file size?

Driver information added.

```
JDBCDriver[
  "Name" -> "HSQL(Standalone)", 
  "Driver" -> "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", 
  "Protocol" -> "jdbc:hsqldb:file:", 
  "Version" -> 3.1, 
  "Description" -> "HSQL Database Engine (In-Process Mode) - Version 2.3.3 -  This ...", 
  "Location" -> "C:\... "]
```

Driver information for the other options available to me.

Derby

```
JDBCDriver[
  "Name" -> "Derby(Embedded)", 
  "Driver" -> "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver", 
  "Protocol" -> "jdbc:derby:", 
  "Version" -> 3.1, 
  "Description" -> "Derby Database Engine (Embedded Mode) - Version 10.12.1.1 - This...",
  "Location" -> "C:\... "]
```

H2

```
JDBCDriver[
  "Name" -> "H2(Embedded)", 
  "Driver" -> "org.h2.Driver", 
  "Protocol" -> "jdbc:h2:", 
  "Version" -> 3.1, 
  "Description" -> "H2 Database Engine (Embedded Mode) - Version 1.3.176 - This...",
  "Location" -> "C:\... "]
```

SQLite

```
JDBCDriver[
  "Name" -> "SQLite", 
  "Driver" -> "org.sqlite.JDBC", 
  "Protocol" -> "jdbc:sqlite:", 
  "Version" -> 3.1, 
  "Description" -> "SQLite using Zentus-derived JDBC Driver - Version 3.8.11.2", 
  "Location" -> "C:\..."]
```

Additional variants include the below. However, I need it all to run on the client's computer. I believe this excludes server and webserver modes.

```
{"Derby(Embedded)", "Derby(Server)", "H2(Embedded)", "H2(Memory)", 
 "H2(Server)", "HSQL(Memory)", "HSQL(Server)", "HSQL(Standalone)", 
 "SQLite", "SQLite(Memory)"}
```

Comment: Which HSQL version are you using? And what prevents you from just trying H2 or SQLite?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Driver information has been added.

Comment: Try building the indexes after the table is loaded.  Or at least time your inserts without indexes to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JonathanFite If I build index after insert is there a way to track the progress of the index build?  If so I will post another question for that answer.

Comment: @JonathanFite Loading without the index is noticeable faster (500MB of 1,800 MB in 6 mins). Will update on how the post load index build performs.

Comment: @JonathanFite The database file size is already 3.4GB before the index creation began. The create index bit has been running for 30 mins but I have no way of tracking how much is completed. The database file size is slowly growing over this time.

Comment: This is taking very long. Index is still building after 3 hrs and database file size is currently at 4.8GB from a source CSV of 1.8GB.  There has be to a better way. Either I am doing something wrong or these Java databases are pretty rubbish for large data (well, at least HSQLDB).

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, those strategies work in SQL for bulk loading data and as you noticed, it went faster.  But if you have to have the indexes and it's going to take that long, it might be better to leave it as is.  At least you know it's the indexes that are killing the insert performance.

Comment: @JonathanFite I eventually killed the process as it was already way too long to be reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a larger Java memory allocation and a larger HSQLDB memory cache size for faster loading of data into large tables.

Add `hsqldb.cache_rows=4000000` and `hsqldb.cache_size=1000000` to the startup configuration for a new database.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem

Comment: Once it gets to the tenth batch(which puts it at the 1 million rows) I get flooded with errors. The first is `JDBC::error : GC overhead limit exceeded`.  I started the Java Virtual Machine with `-Xmx4g` which I should give it 4GB of ram to worth with. Any ideas why it is dying on me.

Comment: Commit the transaction as you insert each batch. If you already do, then reduce  `hsqldb.cache_size`  to an amount that doesn't cause the error.